# javascript canvas tag and stroketext method

Tags: javascript, php, html, canvas

stroke text method doesn't work. The problem is in the following line:

```
cns.strokeText(<?php echo posST($StreamVal[0][0]); ?>,x,y);
```

When I use a numerical value in that array element( [0][0]'s element), no problems occur, and the code works correctly. But when I use a string value, the value doesn't show.

```
<?php
$StreamVal=array(
array("Stream1",80),
array("Stream2",10),
array("Stream3",10),
array("Stream4",10)
);
function posST($Stream)
{
    return $Stream;
}
?>
<script>
var c = document.getElementById("Canvas");
var cns = c.getContext("2d");
var x=50*Math.cos((<?php echo posST($StreamVal[0][1]); ?>*Math.PI)/50)+100;
var y=50*Math.sin((<?php echo posST($StreamVal[0][1]); ?>*Math.PI)/50)+75;
cns.font = "30px Arial";
**cns.strokeText(<?php echo posST($StreamVal[0][0]); ?>,x,y);**  
</script>
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: You are echo'ing the string to js without quotes around it. `...xt('<?php echo posST($StreamVal[0][0]); ?>',x...` If you viewed the source of the page it would look like: `...xt(some text here,x,y);` which it will think you are referencing some variable, not a string.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn is right that you need to enclose your statement in quotes. But you shouldn't mix PHP and JavaScript to begin with. As a good practice always try to avoid this by using JSON via Ajax for example.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use javascript [parseInt](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp) function

```
parseInt(<?php echo posST($StreamVal[0][1]); ?>)
```